# How to add partial check in Ext tree panel

Tags: extjs, checkbox, tree, treeview, panel

I am using Ext.tree.Panel to create the tree structure. Each node has checkbox also. If we checked the parent then all child nodes should be checked. But if we uncheck any child then i need to show parent as partially checked. How display the parent as partially checked?

Answer (score 0):

There is no partial state for a checkbox, only checked or unchecked. What you could do is add a custom handler which detects the change/click event of a child checkbox, finds its parent(or siblings) iterates through them counting the number checked/total then appends that information to the text of the parent node (and unchecks it if checked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement. So what I did is to change the background image of the parent to show a square box to indicate it's half checked. You can play with the DOM the way you want, but the state of the record in your TreeStore won't reflect the change. Most of the times you don't care about that and you'll be interested only in children status (checked/unchecked).